# what do we call the second caller?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

You are on a call, when suddenly another comes in. You want to tell the first caller that another caller is trying to reach you.

What do we call the second caller?

I know this service is called **"call waiting"**, but I want to know if there is a word (or phrase) for describing **the second caller**?

Comment: I've never found a need for this kind of term; if I'm letting the first caller know that there's another call waiting, I'll just say "please hold; I have another call coming in", then I'll switch, tell the second caller "please hold; I'll be right with you; I'm on another call", and switch back.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "call" in "What do we call the second caller?"  Are you looking for a word to use when informing the first caller that you would like to put them on hold for a moment because you have another call coming in?  And is this a mobile phone, not a business phone that sits on a counter or on a desk? And are you speaking to a friend or to a stranger/customer?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo In "What do we call the second caller?", call means "what do we say" or "Is there a word for describing...". I am looking for a word which can describe the second caller, not only for informing the first caller, but also for describing this situation (to anyone else). I thought there might be no difference between using this word for a mobile phone and a business phone, or between using it for a friend or a stranger. If there is, I would be glad to know the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm going to agree with the comment made by Jeff Zeitlin; I, too, will usually tell the first caller:

> I have another call coming in.

But, if you are looking for a word for the caller, one word you could use is ***party***.

The word *party*, of course, has many different meanings. For example, there are birthday parties, rescue parties, and political parties. But there is another meaning for this word:

> ***[party](https://www.wordnik.com/words/party)*** (*noun*)  A person using a telephone

The word *party* does not, by definition, mean "the *second* caller". However, you could use the word *another* as a determiner, and make this work:

> Excuse me, there's **another party** trying to reach me.

I'm not saying that I'd recommend the word *party* over, say, *caller*, or even *person*:

> I'm sorry, there's **another person** calling me; do you mind hanging on for a moment?

In fact, I think *party* almost sounds a little old-fashioned in the context of telecommunications; it reminds me of a bygone era when people used telephone operators instead of cell phones, when children shared the same phone number and land line as their parents.

Nevertheless, I thought this quaint suggestion might be useful and informative to our community of learners.